# Disapear setted background color of GridViewCell on Scroll DataGrid

Tags: wpf, wpfdatagrid, radgridview

I set specific cell background in grid click. But on grid scroll it set back to default. I perefer not to use EnableRowVirtualization as False.
This is My Code:

```
<telerik:RadGridView ItemsSource="{Binding PersonList}" Name="grid"
Height="200" PreviewMouseUp="grid_PreviewMouseUp" >

private void grid_PreviewMouseUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{
    var cell = (sender as RadGridView).CurrentCell;
    cell.Background = Brushes.Aqua;
}
```

Thank

Comment: What do you want to achieve? I mean, you click a cell and its background changes... But what happens when you click another cell? Does the first cell remain colored or should it revert to its former background color? Does clicking a cell do something other than change its color (like setting some property of the item, for instance)?

Comment: my primary problem is that when i scrolling grid and back to first place colored cells set to default background. I want to use this capability in a complex scenario in my project. thank for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Virtualization just remove your cells from memory which not displayed after scrolling. Therefore, you can't just change properties of visual elements. And you need to save information of selected cells in model class. You should use some property(`SelectedColumns`) in your model class for save current
selected column(or columns). You can set this information in click
handler(or as you already describe in question). Then you need to
create binding with converter (for example - `ValueToColorConverter`) and inside is return necessary background color using `SelectedColumns` property and information of current cell.

Example for **GridViewCell**:

```
<Style TargetType="telerik:GridViewCell" BasedOn="{StaticResource GridViewCellStyle}">
    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{Binding Converter={StaticResource ValueToColorConverter}}" />
</Style>
```

Second way - to use [CellStyleSelector](http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/silverlight/controls/radgridview/style-selectors/cell-style-selector)

Comment: I want color cells by user click and not by evaluate value of cells. thank for your comment.

Comment: How I said : _You can set this information in click handler(or as you already describe in question)_

Comment: If you wanna use Virtualization, you have to save information about selected cell in Model or ViewModel.